# Isolate just the element that was clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm just getting started with Angular and running up against some roadblocks in my understanding of certain core concepts.  To better familiarize myself with this new framework I'm attempting to build a trivial application: "Would You Rather?".  I present the user two questions, they pick one, I highlight their choice, and show how many votes each question has from previous users.

It sounds simple but I'm still stuck in a jQuery frame of mind; I want to select the element based on $(this) or $("#id").

I have a factory with an array of question objects.  Each object has a `firstQuestion` and `secondQuestion` key that maps to a question, as well as a `firstVotes` and `secondVotes` key with the corresponding number of votes.  I'm using a `QuestionsCtrl` to control scope and take action when a user makes a choice.

Here's my **index.html** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Would You Rather?</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" ng-app="wouldYouRatherApp">
    <div ng-controller="QuestionsCtrl">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
          <h1 class="col-md-12">Would you rather...</h1>  
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="btn btn-lg btn-{{buttonClass}}" ng-click="recordAnswer('first')">{{question.firstQuestion}}</h2>
            <span class="badge" ng-show="badge.show">{{question.firstVotes}}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
          <h3 class="col-md-12"><small>or</small></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="btn btn-lg btn-{{buttonClass}}" ng-click="recordAnswer('second')">{{question.secondQuestion}}</h2>
            <span class="badge" ng-show="badge.show">{{question.secondVotes}}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" ng-show="showNextQuestion" ng-click="nextQuestion()">Next Question&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my **main.js** file:

```
var app = angular.module("wouldYouRatherApp", []);

app.factory("Badges", function() {
    return {show: false}
})

app.factory("Questions", function() {
    var Questions = [{
        firstQuestion: "Ride a horse?",
        firstVotes: 101,
        secondQuestion: "Ride a cowboy?",
        secondVotes: 212
    },
    {
        firstQuestion: "Kiss a frog?",
        firstVotes: 13,
        secondQuestion: "Lick a slug?",
        secondVotes: 23
    },
    {
        firstQuestion: "Play Monopoly?",
        firstVotes: 12,
        secondQuestion: "Play Risk?",
        secondVotes: 17
    }];
    return Questions;
})

app.controller("QuestionsCtrl", function($scope, Badges, Questions) {
    $scope.question = Questions.shift();
    $scope.buttonClass = 'default';
    $scope.showNextQuestion = false;
    $scope.badge = Badges;

    $scope.recordAnswer = function(choice) {
        console.log("User chose: " + choice);
        $scope.buttonClass = 'success';
        // increment votes badge
        $scope[choice+'Votes'] += 1;
        Badges.show = true;
        $scope.showNextQuestion = true;
    }

    $scope.nextQuestion = function() {
        $scope.question = Questions.shift();
        Badges.show = false;
        $scope.buttonClass = 'default';
        $scope.showNextQuestion = false;
    }
})
```

A live example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/t99TL/2/

The app's expected behavior is as follows:

1. Two questions are presented to the user.
2. The user clicks on one of the buttons.
3. That question is highlighted. And the votes badge is incremented. Both votes badges are displayed.
4. A 'Next Question' button is presented to the user.
5. When he/she clicks on the 'Next Question' button, a new question is loaded.

I feel like I probably need to create a directive for each individual question... but I'm not sure how to start, or if I'm even on the right path.  Any advice on obstacles I'm going to face further down the line is much appreciated (i.e. Updating the votes attribute for the question, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot to change to make it work the way you want. This code is not perfect, just a demonstration.

HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="wouldYouRatherApp">

  <div ng-controller="QuestionsCtrl">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <h1 class="col-md-12">Would you rather...</h1>  
      </div>
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2 class="btn btn-lg btn-{{question.firstQuestion.buttonClass}}" ng-click="recordAnswer(question.firstQuestion)">{{question.firstQuestion.text}}</h2>
          <span class="badge" ng-show="badge.show">{{question.firstQuestion.votes}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row text-center">
        <h3 class="col-md-12"><small>or</small></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2 class="btn btn-lg btn-{{question.secondQuestion.buttonClass}}" ng-click="recordAnswer(question.secondQuestion)">{{question.secondQuestion.text}}</h2>
          <span class="badge" ng-show="badge.show">{{question.secondQuestion.votes}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2 class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" ng-show="showNextQuestion" ng-click="nextQuestion()">Next Question&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("wouldYouRatherApp", []);


app.factory("Badges", function() {
    return {show: false}
})


app.factory("Questions", function() {
    var Questions = [{
        firstQuestion: {
            text:"Ride a horse?",
            votes: 101,
            buttonClass : 'default'
        },
        secondQuestion: {
           text:"Ride a cowboy?",
           votes: 212,
            buttonClass : 'default'
        },
    },
    {
        firstQuestion: {
            text:"Kiss a frog?",
            votes: 13,
            buttonClass : 'default'
        },
        secondQuestion: {
            text:"Lick a slug?",
            votes: 23,
            buttonClass : 'default'
        }
    },
    {
        firstQuestion: {
            text:"Play Monopoly?",
            votes: 12,
            buttonClass : 'default'
        },
        secondQuestion: {
            text:"Play Risk?",
            votes: 17,
            buttonClass : 'default'
        }
    }];
    return Questions;
})


app.controller("QuestionsCtrl", function($scope, Badges, Questions) {
    $scope.question = Questions.shift();
    $scope.buttonClass = 'default';
    $scope.showNextQuestion = false;
    $scope.badge = Badges;

    $scope.recordAnswer = function(choice) {
        choice.buttonClass = 'success';
        choice.votes++;
        Badges.show = true;
        $scope.showNextQuestion = true;
    }

    $scope.nextQuestion = function() {
        $scope.question.firstQuestion.buttonClass = "default";
        $scope.question.secondQuestion.buttonClass = "default";

        $scope.question = Questions.shift();
        Badges.show = false;
        $scope.showNextQuestion = false;
    }
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HKHQe/)